# Java Generating numbers

Tags: java, random, numbers

How would I generate a number between 0.00 and 100? Trying to find out how but I cant get it to work.

Prefer to have a function and then that I can call it like 'getRandom(0.00, 100)'

Comment: Read about Random class(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Comment: Math.Random. Google that!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the question doesn't even show the minimal effort of googling the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Random class. Googling helps...

Googling "java random" spawns the best result as the first. The JavaDoc reference.

So try, `int rand = new Random().nextInt(101)`. That will generate a random number from 0 to 101 **EXCLUSIVE**. So it will generate a random number from 0 to 100.

EDIT: as a comment pointed out, I was incorrect, it goes from 0 to 100 inclusive. An easy off-by-one mistake.

Comment: it will generate you number from **0** to 100, not from 1 to 100

Answer (score 0):

You can use below utility class and call getRandom(int, int) method using

```
 GenerateRandomNumber.getRandom(0, 100)
```

Code Snippet:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Random;

public class GenerateRandomNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomNumberBetween1To100 = getRandom(0,  100);
        System.out.println("Random number between 1 to 100 is: " + randomNumberBetween1To100);
    }
    public static int getRandom(int minNumber, int maxNumber) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(maxNumber - minNumber);
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: not gonna work, try `getRandom(10,15)`, it will generates you number in range (0,4) not (10,15)

Comment: Yeah agree, I purposely given this solution because person has asked for 0 to 100. But yes, change will be required if random-number-in-between-range is not expected. Thanks.